# how to disable the context menu for particular ListView items in Android

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I know this question was asked previously and the reply was to override  onPrepareContextMenu()/onCreateContextMenu(). But I didnt understand and didnt get any solution for it. Please help me how to disable the context menu for particular ListView items.

Comment: override onPrepareContextMenu() and do a check for the current selected list position have a boolean flag to remove all items from the menu  = win.

Comment: can you be more specific about this, I mean i need a sample code to understand it clearly. I cannot figure out how to remove all items from menu for a SPECIFIC list item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opening your context menu depends on your some logic. For example, in method onItemClick (in your listView) you should check content of your item and show or don't show context menu. I don't understand, why it's problem for you?

UPDATE

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.id.list ,mList);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(mListView);

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView , View v,int position, long id) {
                mListView.getItemAtPosition(position); //check current item with your logic and show or don't show contextMenu
                // for example I will show
                mListView.showContextMenu(); //to show
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // add contextmenu items
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // todo some logic...
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

}

May be it will help you... good luck...

Comment: In onCreate(), I am registering my listview with registerForContextMenu(listview) .And in onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) , how i am supposed to enable/disable for particular list item. Suppose take 1st item in ListView. How i am supposed to write that enable/disable code after this - listview.getItemAtPosition(0). ?

Comment: your contextMenu will be show, when you call showContextMenu() method. You will check your item, and if you need show contextMenu you will call showContextMenu() and in other way you won't call it. What is the problem?

Comment: In onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) method there is "int position" parametr. It's position of your current clicked item. You check item by getItemAtPosition(int position) and do something...

Comment: Even without writing showContextMenu() method, my listview is showing the context menu.I have tried the getItemAtPosition(position) but no use.showContextMenu() is showing up for parameter Listview l only.

Comment: Worked like a charm and a bunch of thanks for the example code.Banged my head for many hours and finally got the answer. ThankYou once again.

Comment: Just a note: what actually disables here showing the context menu on each row was the fact that you returned `true` inside `onItemLongClick` method which means the event is not propagated anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can re-register your listview which will cause your `onCreateContextMenu` method to execute again

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExample);
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

And then you can hide or display menu items with which ever logic you want in the `onCreateContextMenu` method

Comment: I buy this. I don't think messing up with `OnItemLongClickListener` is a good idea.